# how to use multi DBContextPool?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EFCore 2.0 Add new feature, DbContext pooling.
i know how to use it in single context,
however, sometimes need multi context in project,

```
public class BContext : DbContext
{
    public BContext(DbContextOptions<BContext> options) : base(options) { }
}

public class AContext : DbContext
{
    public AContext(DbContextOptions<AContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

ConfigureServices

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AContext.InMemory");
});
services.AddDbContextPool<BContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("BContext.InMemory");
});
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly AContext aContext;

    public HomeController(AContext aContext)
    {
        this.aContext = aContext;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When i use any context, exception throw.

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MultiContext.Contexts.BContext]' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MultiContext.Contexts.AContext]'
>   Parameter name: arguments[0]
>      at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
>      at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateArgumentTypes(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments, String methodParamName)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, Expression[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextPool`1.CreateActivator(DbContextOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextPool`1..ctor(DbContextOptions options)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__2`1.b__2_1(IServiceProvider p)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>      at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

Comment: You need add configuration for dependency injection, I mean for this: DbContextOptions<AContext> options

Comment: Looks like this scenario wasn't anticipated. I guess [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9433) is yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. i've found problem. You need to download EF Core, then change constructor for 
DbContextPool< TContext>

original

```
public DbContextPool([NotNull] DbContextOptions options)
```

and change to

```
public DbContextPool([NotNull] DbContextOptions<TContext> options)
```

otherwise DI will use last added options :)

Comment: Please use the answer field only for answering the question. Use comment field to ask for details.

Comment: if you interested, i've changed code https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/9465

Answer (score 1):

Or you can register your own factory of `DbContextPool`

```
services.AddDbContextPool<AContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AContext.InMemory");
});
services.AddDbContextPool<BContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("BContext.InMemory");
});

collection.AddSingleton(svcs => new DbContextPool<AContext>(svcs.GetService<DbContextOptions<AContext>>()));
collection.AddSingleton(svcs => new DbContextPool<BContext>(svcs.GetService<DbContextOptions<BContext>>()));
```